# Matplotlib FuncAnimation only draws one frame

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to do an animation using the `FuncAnimation` module, but my code only produces one frame and then stops. It seems like it doesn't realize what it needs to update. Can you help me what went wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)

def animate(i):
    PLOT.set_data(x[i], np.sin(x[i]))
    print("test")
    return PLOT,

fig = plt.figure()  
sub = fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(x[0], x[-1]), ylim=(-1, 1))
PLOT, = sub.plot([],[])

animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(x), interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)

fig = plt.figure()  
sub = fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(x[0], x[-1]), ylim=(-1, 1))
PLOT, = sub.plot([],[])

def animate(i):
    PLOT.set_data(x[:i], np.sin(x[:i]))
    # print("test")
    return PLOT,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(x), interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

You need to keep a reference to the animation object around, otherwise it gets garbage collected and it's timer goes away.

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1656) to attach a hard-ref to the animation to the underlying `Figure` object.

As written, your code well only plot a single point which won't be visible, I changed it a bit to draw *up to* current index